# Space-evenly display text in React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to display my text with even amount of space per line of text displayed similar to how eBooks display texts. I could only find resources regarding displaying many <View>s in space-evenly or space-between using flexbox justifyContent.

I have a <Text>a lot of text inside....</Text> and I want the text inside should be evenly spaced. How could I space my words inside the <Text>?

```
const TextDisplay = () => {
  const part = part0004_split_010;
  const text_example =
    "fdkfjldjsfljsldfjlskdjflsdjf alkjgdlkjg lkdjgflkdjgkld kdjfauieghjknf uio 23jo1j kldanglk3tlk jasdn lskj jie hgihigehi anvmcnvmcn  ,zmnmx nmf ei nvi nie 2 i2j42in42i n kd nk nskan lk lkdas j92al klkjr1l2or a;z;z;z;  9r3ur9j 39 091 jr1 j a,c n kn oian iong oien voin ow ni ei nwoinq ei n93 n99";

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView style={styles.scrollview}>
          <Text style={styles.text_style}>{text_example}</Text>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

export default TextDisplay;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    borderColor: "red",
    borderWidth: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "grey",
    width: "80%",
  },
  scrollview: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly'
  },
  text_style: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: "black",
  },
});
```

I tried using justifyContent: 'space-evenly' on my scrollView but it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `textAlign:"justify"` in the styles of a `<Text>` to make the text justified.

Comment: Link to the docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/text-style-props#textalign

Comment: Happy to hear. Can you please up vote my answer :)